# meaning of `%1` in linux command `jobs`

Tags: linux

I have seen the following script:

```
$ ./crazy-malloc &
[1] 2817
malloced 3056 MB
$ jobs -x pmap %1
2823: ./crazy-malloc
000cc000 4112K rw--- [ anon ]
004d0000 104K r-x-- /lib/ld-2.3.5.so
004ea000 4K r---- /lib/ld-2.3.5.so
004eb000 4K rw--- /lib/ld-2.3.5.so
004ee000 1168K r-x-- /lib/libc-2.3.5.so
00612000 8K r---- /lib/libc-2.3.5.so
00614000 8K rw--- /lib/libc-2.3.5.so
00616000 8K rw--- [ anon ]
006cf000 124388K rw--- [ anon ]
08048000 4K r-x-- /home/john/examples/mm/crazy-malloc
08049000 4K rw--- /home/john/examples/mm/crazy-malloc
08051000 2882516K rw--- [ anon ]
b7f56000 125424K rw--- [ anon ]
bfa43000 84K rw--- [ stack ]
bfa58000 5140K rw--- [ anon ]
ffffe000 4K ----- [ anon ]
total 3142980K
```

Q1> what is the usage of the line `jobs -x pmap %1`? What does `%1` indicate here?

> jobs -x command [ args ... ]   If  the  -x option is supplied, jobs
>   replaces any jobspec found in command or args with the corre-sponding
>   process group ID, and executes command passing it args, returning its
>   exit status.
>
> pmap - report memory map of a process

Q2> What the first two columns represent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `%1` represents the process which you just started and backgrounded (`./crazy-malloc`, pid 2817). The command `jobs -x pmap %1` expands to `pmap 2817`.
2. The four columns in the output of `pmap` represent, respectively, the base address, size, permissions, and mapped file for each memory region mapped by your process.

Comment: why people use the command `jobs -x pmap %1` instead of simple one `pmap 2817`?

Comment: Because it doesn't depend on you remembering the pid, I guess? I don't know, I don't use that syntax myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

`%1` is the jobspec the paragraph you posted talks about. Basically, if you see line like this

```
[2] 2817
```

when executing a job in background, its jobspec would be `%2`.